# Iteration Through R class

Tags: android

is there any possible way to iterate throught R.raw or R.drawable or any R class? I want to get every id on that folder dynamically.

```
ArrayList resArray = new ArrayList();
foreach(int id : R.raw) {
resArray.add(id);
}
```

or is there any other way?

Comment: I think the question is ovbious enough isn't it? sorry if it is too short :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using java reflection:

```
Class raw = R.raw.class;
Field[] fields = raw.getFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    try {
        Log.i("REFLECTION",
            String.format("%s is %d", field.getName(), field.getInt(null)));
    } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("REFLECTION", String.format("%s threw IllegalAccessException.",
            field.getName()));
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to convert that Field back into int ? I am sorry, Iam not yet to learn Reflection

Comment: `field.getInt(null)` returns an `int` which is the resource id.

Comment: Note that this is comparatively slow, so please cache these results between configuration changes.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Good point. Since R.raw never changes it would be nice to have an immutable map of its ids constructed at compile time. Maybe the best you can do is a static initializer that does this once on class load.

Comment: is it okay to make it static? won't it eat memory on runtime?

Comment: @Matthew Willis: `R.raw` could change, depending on what the developer does. You can create `res/raw-de/` directories just like you can `res/values-de/`. If the developer in question has the chops, a class and static initializer built via a script from the resources as part of the build process is a reasonable solution.

Comment: @Fugogugo: The RAM cost should be on the order of four bytes per resource ID, IIRC. And it is the same cost that you would have by caching the results of the reflection. If you have so many resources that this memory cost is noticeable, you should not be doing any of this.